# cmake FetchContent SOURCE_DIR

Tags: cmake, external-project, fetchcontent

I am trying to use a small subproject in a cmake master project using the `FetchContent` method. Specifically, in the `CMakeLists.txt` of my master project, I have the lines

```
include(FetchContent)
FetchContent_Declare(subproject GIT_REPOSITORY https://url/to/my_subproject)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(subproject)
```

When I enter `cmake` in the master project, the subproject is cloned, but the configuration fails.

Specifically, the `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}` variable in the subproject contains the source directory of the *master* project, rather than that of the subproject, so directories relative to it are incorrect. The `${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}` variable correctly points to the subproject root, and the `${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}` variable correctly points to the current directory in the subproject.

My questions are:

- Is this a developer error / bug in the subproject (should references to the `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}` variable be replaced with `${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}`)?
- Is there a workaround for the master project (Such as using `cmake -P`?)

Comment: "_Is this a developer error / bug in the subproject (should references to the ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR} variable be replaced with ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR})?_" yes. file a ticket to the maintainer of the project or submit the patch upstream to help them out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike to `ExternalProject_Add` function, which configures a subproject as a **separate CMake project**, the `FetchContent_MakeAvailable` effectively calls

```
add_subdirectory(<subproject_source_dir> <binary_dir>)
```

So, when a subproject is configured, it accesses **master variables**. Exception is a variable which is set by the subproject itself, or a variable which is automatically set by CMake according to the scope (like `CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR`).

While ability for a project to be used via FetchContent is useful, not all CMake projects are developed to support such usage. That is, you may fill an issue for a project which uses `CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR` variable in its calculations. But please mark that issue as a "feature request", not a "bug". (Unless the project's documentation explicitly describes the usage via FetchContent).

> Is there a workaround for the master project?

Since the variable `CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR` cannot be set manually, the master project has no other choice than including **modified** subproject.

When call `FetchContent_Declare`, you could specify some executable as `PATCH_COMMAND` option (the option is described in [ExternalProject](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/ExternalProject.html)). That way you may run not only `patch`, but e.g. a `sed` script which replaces `CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR` with some other "scoped" variable.